# Django Post save signal gives error save() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, django

I have been working on following model

```
class Member(BaseModel):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    refer_code = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        unique=True,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
```

and the refer_code was set to be automatically generated when save method is called i.e during creation (not during update) here is my clean method and save method.

```
def clean(self):
    if not self.user.is_member:
        raise DjangoValidationError({'user': _('User must member')})

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self._state.adding:
        self.refer_code = self.user.username
    super(Member, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

post_save.connect(save, sender=User)
```

I followed certain tutorials on youtube but got following error

```
save() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

I want post_save signal to be triggered during creation so I tried created = True but got error.

Answer (score 0):

If your `save` is defined on model then you don't need to use `post_save` signal - `save` will be called automatically when object is saved. In case you still need to use signals - take a look on [arguments defenition](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/signals/#post-save). Here's signal example:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Member)
def your_signal(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    # second part of if expression is needed to avoid recursive
    # save call
    if instance._state.adding and not instance.refer_code:
        instance.refer_code = instance.user.username
        instance.save()
```